# Not having write access for my FTP User for my Wordpress / nginx / ubuntu with SSH

Tags: permissions, ssh, nginx, ftp, wordpress

I deployed a wordpress site on Ubuntu 20.04 using Nginx.

First I did:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Which solved issue I had when uploading plugin.

But now, when I connect FTP with my SSH key, using ubuntu user, I can see the files, but not modify them.

I checked the permissions:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-20-36-190:~/site$ ls -al
total 220
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 18 12:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Mar  5 09:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   405 Feb  6  2020 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19915 Mar 10 00:26 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7345 Mar 10 00:26 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7165 Mar 10 00:26 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 22 15:10 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   351 Feb  6  2020 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2328 Oct  8 21:15 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2913 Feb  6  2020 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3216 Mar  4 17:06 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  3 13:23 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3939 Jul 30  2020 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 25 www-data www-data 12288 Mar 10 00:26 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2496 Feb  6  2020 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3313 Mar 10 00:26 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 44993 Mar 10 00:26 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  8509 Apr 14  2020 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 21125 Mar 10 00:26 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 31328 Mar 10 00:26 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4747 Oct  8 21:15 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3236 Jun  8  2020 xmlrpc.php
```

I tried to do a chmod -R +w , but I couldn't have write access on my files.

I also tried to add ubuntu user to www-data group, with

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

but still, but I couldn't have write access on my files

I did a `chmod -R 777 .` in all my files, and it worked, is it ok to do that, I have heard it could be a security issue ?

What should be the good way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have successfully added your 'ubuntu' account to the group www-data, you can now give your files and directories group write permission.  The reason it was still failing is that the group www-data does not have write.

chmod -R g+w .

Should work for you.

Comment: Yes indeed, it worked, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you need is alternative permissions to make this work..    Which as long as your on a fully functional filesystem such as ext4 you can use Linux Access Control Lists (ACLs).

The following link will get you started..

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists

In effect you can control the default UID and GID settings for newly created files anywhere under the file tree you've configured which is perfect for what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a bind mount to allow the web server access to that tree as user/group www-data and read-only but allow the users read-write access with whatever permissions the need.   I've used this method successfully with both apache and nginx.

Lets assume you have your shared read-write directory in /home/share and that is configured with group permissions for your users to read and write the files there..  Lets assume that www-data is both pid and gid 33.

First make sure you have bindfs installed.. (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bindfs.1.html)

```
sudo apt-get install bindfs
```

Then you do a read-only bind mount which forces the user/group to be www-data :-

```
bindfs -r --force-user=www-data --force-group=www-data /home/share /var/www/html
```

So this masks all of the files created in /home/share in an alternate read-only mount point which is readable via www-data user/groups.